# Avoid login in a java web app using cookies

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, cookies

I'm creating a simple Java webapp using Tomcat 7. In this site only logged users can view the content, so I have a main page **index.jsp** which contains only 2 forms, one to log-in and other to sing-up. Only once the user has logged-in or registered, he can access the website content.

I'd like to avoid users to enter username and password each time, so I think I could use cookies to achieve this, right?

If it's right, I'd like to know how to do it... my first approach is to use a servlet, and use the url of this servlet as the entry point of my webapp, but I'm not sure that this is the best practice at all...

And anyway, if finally it is a good practice, can I set this url as the default entry point or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a filter.  The filter can check for the cookie and handle the authorization pieces in it.
Googling ["jsp remember me"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jsp%20remember%20me&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS459US459&oq=jsp%20remember%20me&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l3j59.1919&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would get you more ideas:

Comment: Thanks @JimBarrows! I've never used filters before, but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for... And also thanks for the sentence to google... I tried others like "avoid login using cookies" and I only found tutorial to avoid cookies :)

Answer (score 1):

It's NOT secure to store passwords in cookies as plain text.

Instead, you can use a long string called 'token' that is issued from the website when you provide your user name and password. See http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice for more details.

Comment: Thanks @reprogrammer, interesting suggestion. But in this case I have to use a concrete DB I can't modify, so I'll have to come up with something else...

Comment: You can use a cache to keep the token->login info, and make sure to write the cache to disk on shutdown, and read it from disk on startup.  Minimizes the risk of keeping the username/password in a cookie on the users browser.  You still have to keep the cache file secure of course.